# phpMyAdmin: secret passphrase?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using MAMP and every time I login to phpMyAdmin, I am getting the following error/warning message:

> the configuration file now needs a secret passphrase (blowfish_secret).

I have not messed around with any of this settings before. Can someone please clarify this error.

Here is the info on my db server:

> Server: Localhost via UNIX socket Server type: MySQL Server version:
>   5.5.34 - Source distribution Protocol version: 10

Comment: See here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PhpMyAdmin#Add_blowfish_secret_passphrase

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, that's only a "secret string" like `"my personal secret"`. Look [here](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cookie-authentication-options).

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense now.

Answer (score 8):

This might help,
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PhpMyAdmin#Add_blowfish_secret_passphrase

If you see the following error message at the bottom of the page when you first log in to /phpmyadmin (using a previously setup MySQL username and password) :

```
ERROR: The configuration file now needs a secret passphrase (blowfish_secret)
```

You need to add a blowfish password to the phpMyAdmin's config file. Edit /etc/webapps/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php and insert a random blowfish "password" in the line

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = ; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */
```

It should now look something like this:

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'qtdRoGmbc9{8IZr323xYcSN]0s)r$9b_JUnb{~Xz'; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */
```

This all assumes you've already properly created the config file,

```
cp config.sample.inc.php config.inc.php
```

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem as OP. However, I already added a password to the config file. Do you have any clue what the reason for this could be? I did upgrade from PHP 7.3 to 7.4, but I guess that wouldn't change anything? Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The configuration file now needs a secret passphrase (blowfish_secret).

You’ll see this error after every installation of phpmyadmin.

To resolve this issue, just open `config.inc.php` ( or rename `config.sample.inc.php` to `config.inc.php` if you haven’t done so yet ) and change this line

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = ''; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */
```

to

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'y[/qlva{kNheGD5hfzFLrNoS-ZX\zQ/';
```

To generate new blowfish secret, simply hit this https://phpsolved.com/phpmyadmin-blowfish-secret-generator/?g=5d94be5065c70

Answer (score 1):

Any string with 32 chars long will do, sample:

```
^M5Pk*FD1cQp9*M9!U!@c59p@huqsphZ
```

So, your final code will look like:

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = '^M5Pk*FD1cQp9*M9!U!@c59p@huqsphZ';
```

You may generate it online, set Password Length to 32:

[lastpass password generator](https://www.lastpass.com/features/password-generator)

Answer (score 1):

**For Ubuntu 20.04 Or 22.04 with Nginx,**

**Step 1:-**

Create a new custom settings file inside the `/etc/phpmyadmin/conf.d` directory and name it `pma_secure.php`:

```
sudo nano /etc/phpmyadmin/conf.d/pma_secure.php
```

Then add the following content to the new file:

```
<?php

# PhpMyAdmin Settings
# This should be set to a random string of at least 32 chars
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'CHANGE_THIS_TO_A_STRING_OF_32_RANDOM_CHARACTERS';

$i=0;
$i++;

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowRoot'] = true; //set it false if you want to disable logins by the root MySQL user     
?>
```

**Step 2:-**

Update the line that reads 'CHANGE_THIS_TO_A_STRING_OF_32_RANDOM_CHARACTERS' to a random string containing at least 32 characters.

**Note:-** The changes will apply automatically. You just need to logout and login PhpMyAdmin.